# Pandas doesn't split EIA API Data into two different columsn for easy access

Tags: pandas

I am importing EIA data which contains weekly storage data. The first column in the reported week and second is storage.
When I import the data it shows two columns. First column has no title and second one as following title "Weekly Lower 48 States Natural Gas Working Underground Storage, Weekly (Billion Cubic Feet)".
I would like to plot the data using matplotlib but I need to separate the columns first. I used df.iloc[100:,:0] and this gives the first column which is the week but I somehow cannot separate the second column.

```
 import eia
 import pandas as pd
 import os

 api_key = "mykey"
 api = eia.API(api_key)
 series_search = api.data_by_series(series='NG.NW2_EPG0_SWO_R48_BCF.W')

 df = pd.DataFrame(series_search)
 df1 = df.iloc[100:,:0]
```

## Code Output

This output is sample of all 486 rows. When I use df.shape command it shows as (486, 1) when it should show (486, 2 )

```
        2010 0101 01    3117
        2010 0108 08    2850
        2010 0115 15    2607
        2010 0122 22    2521 
        2019 0322 22    1107
        2019 0329 29    1130
        2019 0405 05    1155
        2019 0412 12    1247
        2019 0419 19    1339
```

Comment: The first columns is set as index right now. To get it as a column use `df.reset_index(inplace=True)`

Comment: Thanks it worked. Follow up question. When I tried to use df['Week'] = df['Week'].astype('datetime64[ns]') to convert into datetime it gave me following error " ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', '2010 0101 01')"

Comment: Well, if I look at your date, how is it formatted? What are the last numbers? those are not hours,since I see 29 and we only have 24 hours. So now I see YYYY MMDD ??

Comment: They are essentially repetition of date on that particular month which I don't know how to truncate because if the same file is downloaded directly to excel it is perfect.

Comment: Can someone please help me how to parse this column? . The code I am using is #df['Week'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Week'], format = "%Y %m%d  "). This code is working but it says the last two characters are remaining and I don't really need those.

Answer (score 0):

You can first cut the last 3 characters of the string and then convert it to datetime:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].str[:-3], format='%Y %m%d')
```

---

```
print(df)
        Date  Value
0 2010-01-01   3117
1 2010-01-08   2850
2 2010-01-15   2607
3 2010-01-22   2521
4 2019-03-22   1107
5 2019-03-29   1130
6 2019-04-05   1155
7 2019-04-12   1247
8 2019-04-19   1339
```